# Windows 7: Is there a keyboard shortcut for setting a music file rating?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, rating

Usually you would have to right click on a track in Windows Explorer, then choose Properties, then Details and then set a Rating. Was wondering if there is a faster way?

Answer (score 1):

Sure: add *Rating* to the columns displayed in Windows Explorer.

[image: Adding a column to Explorer]

Right-click on the column header, select rating in the drop-down.

To make this a default layout:

- Right-click the parent folder and select properties.
- On the *Customize* tab optimize for *Music* and select *Also apply this... to subfolders*.

[image: Music properties]

- Then, in Windows Explorer *[Folder] Options*, click on *Apply to Folders*.

[image: Explorer Options dlg]

From now on (unless a Windows update resets this), every time you open a *Music* folder, *Rating* will be displayed.

You can also add *Length*, *Bit Rate* and other fields.

Comment: I've edited the question, it's not what I meant. I meant a shortcut to set a rating to a music file like 5 stars not have it in the menu. Like maybe adding a shortcut in the context menu, you right click on the track and then select the rating.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way.

Click on 'Details pane' on the top left. When the details pane appears on the right hand side you can just click on the desired rating and then click on save, as below:

[image]